# Akka StreamRefs - IllegalStateException (Saw RemoteStreamCompleted while in state UpstreamTerminated)

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I'm trying to send stream of audio from service A to service B with the usage of akka stream refs (akka-streams library version: 2.6.3). Everything is working rather good, except for the fact that once in a month an exception (With daily usage of this service being around 50k calls per day or so) is thrown in the akka stream ref, and I can't find the cause of the problem.

The stacktrace for error is following:

```
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: [SourceRef-46] Saw RemoteStreamCompleted(37) while in state UpstreamTerminated(Actor[akka://system-name@serviceA:34363/system/Materializers/StreamSupervisor-3/$$S4-SinkRef-3405#-939568637]), should never happen
            at akka.stream.impl.streamref.SourceRefStageImpl$$anon$1.$anonfun$receiveRemoteMessage$1(SourceRefImpl.scala:285)
            at akka.stream.impl.streamref.SourceRefStageImpl$$anon$1.$anonfun$receiveRemoteMessage$1$adapted(SourceRefImpl.scala:196)
            at akka.stream.stage.GraphStageLogic$StageActor.internalReceive(GraphStage.scala:243)
            at akka.stream.stage.GraphStageLogic$StageActor.$anonfun$callback$1(GraphStage.scala:202)
            at akka.stream.stage.GraphStageLogic$StageActor.$anonfun$callback$1$adapted(GraphStage.scala:202)
            at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.runAsyncInput(GraphInterpreter.scala:466)
            at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:497)
            at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:599)
            at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:768)
            at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:783)
            at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:534)
            at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:532)
            at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:690)
            ... 11 common frames omitted
```

The code responsible for pushing audio through SourceRef in service A:

```
Materializer materializer = Materializer.createMaterializer(actorSystem);
AudioExtractor extractor = new AudioExtractorImpl("/path/to/audio/file"); // gets all audio bytes from audio file and puts them into chunks (byte arrays of certain length)
List<AudioChunk> audioChunkList = extractor.getChunkedBytesIntoList();
SourceRef<AudioChunk> sourceRef = Source.from(audioChunkList)
      .runWith(StreamRefs.sourceRef(), materializer);
// wrap the sourceRef into msg
serviceBActor.tell(wrappedAudioSourceRefInMsg, getSelf());
```

Whereas code responsible for accepting audio in service B:

```
private final List<AudioChunk> audioChunksBuffer = new ArrayList<>();
private final Materializer materializer;

public Receive createReceive() {
      return receiveBuilder.match(WrappedAudioSourceRefInMsg.class, response -> {
            response.getSourceRef()
                  .getSource()
                  .runWith(Sink.forEach(chunk -> audioChunksBuffer.add(chunk)), materializer); 
      }).build();
}
```

What I've confirmed is that this error always happens after all audio has been sent from service A, and the stream completed. I can't figure out though why is the SourceRef receiving `RemoteStreamCompleted` while in state `UpstreamTerminated`. Especially frustrating is the part of `should never happen` in the message. :|

Any help with this would be much welcome.

Comment: "Should never happen" means you found a bug :) Can you file an issue at https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/new?template=---bug-report.md ? Thanks!

Comment: Aye thanks for the info, posted bug there: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/28852

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing, bug in akka reported here: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/28852